# Need help with a regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hi I'm trying to right a regular expression that will take a string and ensure it starts with an 'R' and is followed by 4 numeric digits then anything

eg. RXXXX.................

Can anybody help me with this? This is for ASP.NET

Comment: This is so terribly _basic_ regex, I'd suggest you take half an hour of your life to just gloss over http://www.regular-expressions.info/, after which you should just plain know.

Comment: Or he can spend 2 minutes of his life asking a question, learning something and saving time in the process. What is unnecessary is people like you giving him crap for it.

Comment: Thank you Travis, I'm not that experienced and any help is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it to be at the beginning of the line, not anywhere. Also, for efficiency, you dont want the `.+` or `.*` at the end because that will match unnecessary characters. So the following regex is what you really want:

```
^R\d{4}
```

Comment: Its funny, I was thinking about efficiency and removed the $ as I was typing my answer. Don't know how it didn't dawn on me to remove the .*  You get my vote! Since his understanding of basic regexes is nil, the whole case-sensitivity thing might be something to point out as I did.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it...

```
^R\d{4}.*$
```

- `\d{4}` matches 4 digits
- `.*` is simply a way to match any character 0 or more times
- the beginning `^` and end `$` anchors ensure that nothing precedes or follows

As Vincent suggested, for your specific task it could even be simplified to this...

```
^R\d{4}
```

Because as you stated, it doesn't really matter what follows.

Comment: `.*$` is useless, you can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`/^R\d{4}.*/`   and set the case insensitive option unless you only want capital R's

Answer (score 0):

```
^R\d{4}.*
```

- The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string.
- `\d` matches any numeric character (it's the same as [0-9])
- `{4}` indicates that there must be exactly 4 numbers, and
- `.*` matches 0 or more other characters

To use:

```
    string input = "R0012 etc..";

    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^R\d{4}.*", RexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
       // Success!
    }
```

Note the use of `RexOptions.IgnoreCase` to ignore the case of the letter R (so it'll match strings which start with r.  Leave this out if you don't want to undertake a case insensitive match.